# BibTex misc references show first three letters instead of number when cited in text

Tags: bibtex, citing

I'm using BibTex @misc for citing websites, my entries all look like this:

```
    @misc{test,
    author =       {},
    key =          {},
    year =         {},
    title =        {Test},
    howpublished = {\url{https://test.com}},
    note =         {Last accessed: 2018-08-25},
    }
```

In my text I cite them like this:

```
    Hello world \cite{test}
```

This results in:

Hello world [tes]

How can I achieve a result like this?:

Hello world [1]

A workaround I found so far is adding a number in the key, but to be honest I don't want to asign the numbers manually as this is very error prone, I'd prefer if it could be achieved automatically somehow (without adding author or year, as I don't have that information for most websites).

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please tell us which bibliography style you employ. (Hint: It's the argument of the `\bibliographystyle` directive.) Is it the `alpha` style? If, consider using `plain` (or some other bibliography style that generates numeric citation call-outs) instead. After changing the argument of `\bibliographystyle`, be sure to run a full recompile cycle (latex, bibtex, and latex twice more) to fully propagate all changes.

Comment: Do also check if your document maybe has more than one `\bibliograpystyle` directive. If so, delete the directive(s) that shouldn't be there and perform a full recompile cycle.